# Javascript method assignment when no brackets

Tags: javascript

I have a java script as below

```
foo(){

return "hello";

}

var myVar=foo;
```

What will get assigned to myVar?

Comment: Nothing, it will fail with a SyntaxError. If you put `function` before the first line, then `myVar` will be an alias for `foo`.

Comment: Perhaps a mis-understanding of ES6 'arrow' (lambda) functions? Parts of this have been back-ported to some browsers' JS engines and some (like Firefox) already had alternate implementations. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/eight-cool-features-coming-in-es6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you initialize it with function keyword:

```
function foo() {
    return "hello";
}
```

then it is possible as in JavaScript in function is a Data Type so you initialized a variable named foo and then assign another variable.

```
var myVar = foo;
```

Calling now myVar() will call function as it has reference to that function now.

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hRSY2/)

Answer (score 1):

SyntaxError Error.

I think what you want is this? In this case foo is an alias for this funciton defined

```
var foo = function(){
return "hello";
}
```